# Change property value in Alamofire function call

Tags: swift, alamofire

I am beginning to Alamofire recently. I want to use Alamofire to send a simple GET request:

```
import Alamofire

class Test{
    var url:String = "www.github.com"
    var i: Int = 1

    func change(){
        Alamofire.request(url, method:.get).responseString { response in
            self.i += 1
            print(self.i)
        }
        print(i)
    }
}
```

I want to change property `i` of class Test from 1 to 2 in Alamofire function call. And print results on console to see what would happen. I expect the output will be

> 2 2

but the real output is

> 1 2

!! I feel so confused about this result. Why it's not `2 2` or `2 1` but `1 2`? what really happened during the function call? Why the property can't be changed?

Comment: { response in
            self.i += 1
            print(self.i)
        }

Comment: this closer will execute after some time(when server respond)

Comment: real out put is real!!

Comment: The request works asynchronously. The response is returned much later.

Comment: you need to understand `threading` and `async` vs `sync`

Comment: @SPatel Thanks for your help. I thought wrong that it would run step by step(code by code).

Answer (score 0):

Because Alamofire request is an async, `print(i)` function runs before `print(self.i)` . You can achieve what you want by waiting the result of Alamofire with `DispatchGroup()`. However, I do not recommend it.

You can get more Info about using Dispatch on Alamofire:

[iOS - swift 3 - DispatchGroup](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41654959/ios-swift-3-dispatchgroup)

Why It is a bad approach @Rob answered it very clearly on below post:

[Synchronous Alamofire Request with DispatchGroup](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47718265/synchronous-alamofire-request-with-dispatchgroup)